# Error creating bean with name 'embeddedKafka': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is kafka.common.KafkaException:

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-contract

I am using the spring cloud contrat to test a kafkaListsener of my service. I use EmbeddedKafka together with the spring cloud contract.

The listener in my service is implemeneted by @KafkaListener from spring kafka.

The contract test I have is like below:

```
@EmbeddedKafka
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ServiceApplication.class},
        properties = {"stubrunner.kafka.enabled=true",
                "stubrunner.stream.enabled=false",
                "spring.cloud.stream.function.autodetect=false"})
public class EventContractTest {

    @Autowired
    private StubTrigger stubTrigger;

    @SpyBean
    @Qualifier("KafkaEventListener")
    private EventListener eventListener;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {   
        Mockito.doNothing().when(eventListener).onEventReceived(any(), any());
    }
    
    @Test
    public void kafkaEventTest() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        stubTrigger.trigger("kafka-event");

        ArgumentCaptor<Event> eventArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Event.class);
        ArgumentCaptor<Bytes> headerArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Bytes.class);
        verify(eventListener, timeout(5000).times(1)).
                onEventReceived(eventArgumentCaptor.capture(), headerArgumentCaptor.capture());
  ....
    }

   @Test
    public void kafkaEventTest2() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        stubTrigger.trigger("kafka-event-2");

        ArgumentCaptor<Event> eventArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Event.class);
        ArgumentCaptor<Bytes> headerArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Bytes.class);
        verify(eventListener, timeout(5000).times(1)).
                onEventReceived(eventArgumentCaptor.capture(), headerArgumentCaptor.capture());
    ....
    }
}
```

when run the tests case, in most cases it will pass, but it will randomlly fail with the following exception:

> givenEventFromContract_whenCancelSubscription_thenTriggerSubscriptionChangedKafkaEvent
> Time elapsed: 0.002 s <<< ERROR! 14:12:43
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
> 14:12:43 Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'embeddedKafka': Invocation of init method
> failed; nested exception is kafka.common.KafkaException: 14:12:43
> Caused by: kafka.common.KafkaException: 14:12:43 Caused by:
> java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException 14:12:43 14:12:43 [ERROR]
> givenEventFromContract_whenDeleteSubscription_thenTriggerSubscriptionDeletedKafkaEvent
> Time elapsed: 25.891 s <<< ERROR! 14:12:43
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
> 14:12:43 at

And below are my kafka relevant configuration:

```
# -- Kafka with PLAINTEXT authentication --
com.sap.kafka.enabled=false
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=test
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.auto.offset.reset=earliest
spring.kafka.topics.default.replication-factor=1
spring.kafka.topics.default.partition-count=1
spring.kafka.topics.default.min-in-sync-replicas=1
```

Does someone know what was the issue? is this a bug of spring kafka?

Comment: I feel like you've cut off part of the stacktrace

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have edited the question and paste all the error log I have, there is not much useful information there

Comment: I was trying to see what it timed out trying to connect to. For example, is it trying to use the correct IP/port? Or in other words, where are you overriding `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers`, or your KafkaTemplate values to actually _use_ the embedded broker?

Comment: I pasted my configuration in the question. Yes the kafkaTemplate use the embedded broker, I checked this before